# PayUmoney integration in android sdk 28 error occured while adding dependency, gradle sync failed

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> dependencies

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
         implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
         testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
         androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.4.4'
        }
```

> error

This is the error generated while gradle sync.
If sdk version is 27 the only gradle sync is succesfull.

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\gagan\AndroidPayment\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1114: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
C:\Users\gagan\AndroidPayment\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1114: error: resource previously defined here.

Command: C:\Users\gagan\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\ae5ba3713e4c882dbabd6f009a856f88\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\gagan\AndroidPayment\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\gagan\AndroidPayment\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Answer (score 0):

> duplicate value for resource 'attr/`layout_anchorGravity`'
>
> resource **previously defined here**.

Sometimes IDE might get confused because of duplicate defined resources. So, go to `values.xml` and find:

```
layout_anchorGravity
```

And remove the other one. If this didn't solve the issue and you are sure that that's not duplicate, try to clean your project.

Comment: there is only 1 layout_anchorGravity in values.xml file,i also tried clean the project but it is not working

Comment: Can’t you remove that attributes to see if that causes the issue?

Comment: I think its not supporting sdk 28

Comment: It's not actually about supporting. I'm wondering why would you need that in there? Couldn't you add it in the xml layout? Sounds useless to me in values.xml.

Comment: should i delete it from values.xml

Comment: Well, we use it to anchor views in **xml layouts**. So I guess, yes. You should remove it from there and use it like:  `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"` in your FABS or etc in your **xml layout**.

Comment: i tried deleting it but it rewrite the file values.xml and layout_anchorGravity is added again

Comment: Are you sure you've deleted from the right `values.xml` file? That could be the merged `values.xml` which you've deleted. Go to `res/values.xml` then delete.

Comment: there is only 1 values.xml file in the whole project.